# Why when creating a wpf project adding webbrowser to designer i'm getting errors in the xmal file?

Tags: c#, wpf

I dragged webbrowser control from toolbox to the designer.

This is the code in MainWindow.xmal

```
<Window x:Class="WPFWebBrowser.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="My Web Browser" WindowState="Normal" Loaded="Window_Loaded" WindowStyle="ThreeDBorderWindow" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" Height="529" Width="731">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="&lt;&lt;" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,5,0,0" Name="MyBack" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="25" ToolTip="Backword" Click="MyBack_Click" />
        <WebBrowser Height="445" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,33,0,0" Name="MyWebBrowser" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="687" LoadCompleted="MyWebBrowser_LoadCompleted" />
        <TextBox Height="23" Margin="103,5,12,0" Name="MyTextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Button Content="|&gt;" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="41,5,0,0" Name="MyGo" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="25" ToolTip="Go" Click="MyGo_Click" />
        <Button Content="&gt;&gt;" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,5,612,0" Name="MyForward" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="25" ToolTip="Forward" Click="MyForward_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I have two problems.

First i don't have the Window_Loaded event in the run time code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WPFWebBrowser
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

The second problem is that in the MainWindow.xmal i'm getting 5 errors

Error 1
'WPFWebBrowser.MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'Window_Loaded' and no extension method 'Window_Loaded' accepting a first argument of type 'WPFWebBrowser.MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error 2
'WPFWebBrowser.MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'MyBack_Click' and no extension method 'MyBack_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'WPFWebBrowser.MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error 3
'WPFWebBrowser.MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'MyWebBrowser_LoadCompleted' and no extension method 'MyWebBrowser_LoadCompleted' accepting a first argument of type 'WPFWebBrowser.MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error 4
'WPFWebBrowser.MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'MyGo_Click' and no extension method 'MyGo_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'WPFWebBrowser.MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error 5
'WPFWebBrowser.MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'MyForward_Click' and no extension method 'MyForward_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'WPFWebBrowser.MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Am i missing a dll i should reference to my project ?

PresentationCore dll is already referenced.
Same as PresentationFramework and WindowsBase

Comment: I'm not familiar with WPF, but I believe the errors are telling you that you need to implement the methods `Window_Loaded`, `MyBack_Click`, `MyWebBrowser_LoadCompleted`, `MyGo_Click` and `MyForward_Click` in your code behind.  See [WPF WebBrowserControl](http://www.dotnetperls.com/webbrowser-wpf) for an example.

Comment: Tim you right thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although implementing the 'Click' events in your code behind will make that code work you really need to take a look at MVVM....

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126249/MVVM-Pattern-in-WPF-A-Simple-Tutorial-for-Absolute

Take my word for it, any project that is more than a few lines AND doesn't use MVVM will be unmaintainable spaghetti code....  I have seen (and sadly had to work on) such projects so PLEASE, do it right BECAUSE one day I might have to work on YOUR code myself........